# Testing GET endpoint, using mocha and chai, AssertionError

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test my GET endpoint, but get this error:

```
  Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (_bsontype, id) } to equal '5be02038cf97ed1cc47feb8a'
```

My test is:

```
  it("it should GET a user by the given id", done => {
        let newUser = new User({
            email: "bloggs@test.com",
            givenName: "Willmott",
            familyName: "Bloggs"
        });

        newUser.save((err, newUser) => {
            let { _id: id } = newUser;

            chai
                .request(app)
                .get("/users/" + id)
                .send(newUser)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    let { body: { _id } } = res;

                    expect(id).to.equal(_id);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
```

How can I get `expect(id).to.equal(_id);` to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of them is an Object (`_id`) and the other is a string (`id`). You probably don't want to compare the entire object, but rather some property on the object. Considering this looks like a database lookup using a bson object, my guess is you might be able to call `toString()` on it? At least, that might work if this is, in fact, a [MongoDB UserId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/#ObjectId.toString):

```
expect(id).to.equal(_id.toString());
```